# Nant change Target Framework to match project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, frameworks, nant

I upgraded my project from .NET 3.5 to 4.5. It's working locally but not building on the server, and the problem is that Nant is trying to use MSBuild 3.5. I ran Nant locally and although it's succeeding, it says 'Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0' and then '[property] Target framework changed to "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5'. What do I need to change in the nant.exe.config file to make it run the right version?

Answer (score 0):

In case you (or anyone else for that matter) are still looking for an answer, check https://alastaircrabtree.com/how-to-build-a-visual-studio-2013-or-2015-solution-on-a-build-server-using-nant/